Set Existing Downloaded and Updated SDK for new Installation of Android Studio
I have downloaded and installed all packages and images and . . . of android studio in following folder and path:
C:\Users\pc55\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
After that I've installed new windows and new android studio and I've set the path as SDK path.
as follow you can see that in android studio there is no any SDK and image and . . .
How I can Import them without download them again.

I've searched from internet and I've don every thing that I found from internet even from stack-overflow website. but they were not working.

Can you confirm if the sdk images available at this location: C:\Users\pc55\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Yes. there are images in folder of "system-images" more than 95 gigabaytes and I've downloaded all packages and images before new windows installation in previous windows.
